# Preload page on hover and link on click

Tags: javascript, ajax

I'm playing around with a possibility to preload a page using ajax on hover over a button and have this page available quicker on click on this button. I'm quite at the beginning and can't really find a good solution for this / might be totally wrong. Here is what I have tried, looks like a little promissing for me:

```
document.getElementById('link').addEventListener('mouseover',function() {
    var r = new XMLHttpRequest();
    r.open("POST", "index.php", true);
    r.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (r.readyState != 4 || r.status != 200) return;
         document.getElementById('link').addEventListener('click',function() {
            window.location.assign('index.php');
        });
    };
    r.send('');
});
```

But I don't think that does it.

Can someone point me in a direction **without** sharing code/solutions? I'm mainly interested in how I can achieve this by myself - is ajax the right way to start?

I'm looking for a javascript only solution

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need a bit of a framework for subbing out the page content and managing what's in the URL *without* sending another request to the server and reloading the page.

[Push state](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history) can help with the URL manipulation.

You would need to replace the body of your page (or less, depending on your markup, maybe just everything inside `#container` or whatever you have on the page) when you received a partial of HTML from your server via AJAX.

Look into how something like Rails' [TurboLinks](http://railscasts.com/episodes/390-turbolinks) uses an approach called `PJAX` to quickly navigate pages. Then the prefetching on hover could be layered on top of an approach like that.

More reading: http://pjax.herokuapp.com/